# AWS async system with Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, asynchronous

I am trying to create a async system on AWS that should have the following workflow:

- The gateway lambda (*invoker*) receives a POST request to query some data from the client.
- It then checks the request. If valid, send the request to the main lambda function (*data parsing*), and return 200OK to the client.
- The *data parsing* function returns the results in a JSON file to the *invoker*. It then fowards that very JSON file to another API for data storage.

The system has been operating fine in sync mode. But when I switch to async, lots of problems occured.

- The *invoker* successfully invoked the *data parsing* function, but it cannot receive the JSON response from that very function.
- In case of success, I also have no idea how to forward the received JSON file to the needed API.
- There is a lot of optimization problems along the way.

Here is my shitcode in the *invoker* function:

```
import json
import requests
import boto3
 
# Define the client to interact with AWS Lambda
client = boto3.client('lambda')
 
def lambda_handler(event,context):
    if 'statusCode' in event:
        # Upon receiving JSON data
        # Making a PUT request
        link = 'This is the link of the API'
        r = requests.put(link, data=event)
    else:
        # Upon receiving a POST request
        response = client.invoke(
            FunctionName = 'The name of the data parsing function',
            InvocationType = 'Event',
            Payload = json.dumps(event)
        )
    return {'statusCode': 200}
```

Here is some piece of codes in the *data parsing* function

```
import json
import boto3
import time

lam = boto3.client('lambda')

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    # Some queries stuffs, please don't mind

    #3. Construct http response object
    responseObject = {}
    responseObject['statusCode'] = 200
    responseObject['headers'] = {}
    responseObject['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    responseObject['body'] = Output
    
    #4. Return the response object
    response = lam.invoke(
        FunctionName = 'Name of the invoker function',
        InvocationType = 'RequestResponse',
    return responseObject
```

Please note that all the AWS and async concepts is very new to me, as I am only an intern. What can I do now to resolve my problems? Thank you.

P/s: To clarify my question, what I need to run asynchronously is the *invoker* function. Meaning, the client sends a request, then receives a 200OK response; meanwhile my *data parsing* function processes the query and send the requested data to another API.

Comment: It would be better to decouple your two functions. For example `f1-->SQS queue--> f2`. Obviously, you need some mechanism to query for results later on. For f2 can store the results in DynamoDb, while f1 returns some id to the client. The client can use the id to pool for results.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're after. Which are you wanting to run async? The invoker needs to synchronous because you want the caller to receive information about what took place, so they must wait, in either case. If you want to run async, you have to implement some way to get the results, because it is discarded by Lambda.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about SQS, Marcin. I will look into it, but for the meantime, is there anything I can do with my code to fix the current issues?